# Array elements not mutating inside for of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let alphArr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
  let n = 13;
  let arr = str.split("");
  let len = alphArr.length;

  for (let i of arr) {
    if (alphArr.includes(i)) {
      if (alphArr.indexOf(i) + n <= len - 1) {
        i = (alphArr[alphArr.indexOf(i) + n])
        console.log(i) // This is as expected
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(arr) // Array itself did not mutate and is showing the initial array. 
  return str;
}

rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

The value of `i` inside the second `if` statement is proper as can be seen in the `console.log` statement but the array in itself did not mutate. Why was that?

P.S. I've solved it by using `map` function and it works properly because `map` function does not mutate the original array.

Comment: what are you trying to do and what is the expected result?

Comment: Try console.log `alphArr[alphArr.indexOf(i)+n]`

Comment: assigning to `i` does not change the array. You are merely reassigning an unrelated variable in this case.

Comment: @VLAZ ohkay... but why is it an unrelated variable. I'd assume it was the current element of the array. Please elaborate a bit more and share any documentation if available. I'd really like to get to the bottom of this and would be very grateful .

Comment: It's the *value* of the current array item. However, changing it won't change the array, since [JavaScript is not pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: @VLAZ Now I get it. Its due to the pass by value as its just represents the value of the element. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: @HWSiew Actually its just part of the entire problem that i needed to solve. My bad. I should have provided the entire context but then it was enough for the specific query that I had.

Comment: @luekbaja That works. I get it now as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that your code can be simplified:

```js
let rot = (str, n, asciiStart='A'.charCodeAt(0), asciiEnd='Z'.charCodeAt(0), asciiRange=asciiEnd-asciiStart+1) =>
  str.split('')
    .map(c => {
      let code = c.charCodeAt(0) - asciiStart;
      if (code >= 0 && code <= asciiRange) code = (code + n) % asciiRange;
      return String.fromCharCode(asciiStart + code);
    })
    .join('');

let inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

inp.addEventListener('input', () => p.innerHTML = rot(inp.value, 13));
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test here (use capital letters)"/>
<p></p>
```

Your code wasn't working because replacing the value of `i` does not effect the array index that `i` was initially based off of. Once you define `i`, it doesn't remember how it was defined (e.g. it doesn't think to itself, "I originated from a value within an array')

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly set value to element in for of loop try the following...

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let alphArr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");

  let n = 13;
  let arr = str.split("");
  let len = alphArr.length;

  let j=0
  for (let i of arr) {
    if (alphArr.includes(i)) {
      if (alphArr.indexOf(i) + n <= len - 1) {

        arr[j]= (alphArr[alphArr.indexOf(i) + n])
        console.log(i) // This is as expected

      }
    }
    j++
  }
  console.log(arr) // Array itself did not mutate and is showing the initial array. 


  return str;
}

rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Comment: If you are going to use a loop counter, you may as well use a regular loop `for (let i = 0;  i < arr.length;  i++)` and use `arr[i]` inside it. Mixing a `for..of` and counters is just messy. A better solution would be to just iterate over the entries in the array, which includes the index: `for (let [index, element] of arr.entries())`

Comment: Yes I would have done that for my code but here I used the code which was provided by the questioner.

Comment: Sorry for messy solution

Comment: I didn't know that you couldn't do and I didn't find any documentation saying it can't be done. Please share if you have if you find something.

Comment: The element in for of loop only contains the value of a particular property you can see it on MDN docs.

Comment: I got the answer. It's because of the pass by value condition.

Comment: Thank you Parth. You're spot on! VLAZ pointed it out above and it just rung a bell.

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `for of` loop you should use `map` to create a new array and used the newly mapped array. Fixed fulling working example:

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let alphArr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");

  let n = 13;
  let arr = str.split("");
  let len = alphArr.length;

  arr = arr.map((i) => {
    if (alphArr.includes(i)) {
      let index = (alphArr.indexOf(i) + n) % len;
        return alphArr[index];
      }
     return i;
  });

  return arr.join("");
}

console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC")); // logs "FREE CODE CAMP"
```

Comment: I did solve it with map as it does not mutate the original array as Matt pointed out but I'm just confused as to why the original array did not get mutated in this case.

Comment: I got the answer thanks to VLAZ. It's because of the pass by value thing and that's why alphArr[alphArr.indexOf(i)+n] would work.